# How to send messages using Wifi

Tags: android, smsmanager

I want to develop a messenger like whatsapp. Attached code is working for sms can i use it by **modifying it** to send text over the internet

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand how text messaging works. It doesn't work over WIFI.

Comment: Can you provide me a code that i can use for send messages using wifi .

Comment: If your looking to send SMS messages over WiFi then there is no solution.

Comment: There are many Apps that send messages over Wifi  For Example WhatsApp , Viber.

Comment: And they use custom backend servers and infrastructure to distribute those messages. What your asking isn't something you can just code and go.

Comment: Okay i got it .Thank you . 
So can you guide me that how can i use those custom backend services  so that i can make app like whatsApp .

Answer (score 1):

Wellcome to Stackoverflow. Your should provide your code for checking if it is correct.

Supposing it is right. Did you allow to send message by your application?

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

**Note**: For definition SMS is a technology provided by SIM. If you want to use wifi for sending SMS you could use a service provided by someone which let you connect to it and then they will send the SMS through its servers. Another option is using some client-service technology android-to-android.

Comment: Yes i added . Above code works fine .
But i want to  send messages using wifi .
Above code sends messages using Sim

Comment: Hi @zeeshansarfraz, Edited

Comment: Thanks for reply @EliasMp
But Brother plz  provide me a code that i can use to send messages using wifi .

Comment: I can´t. You need to find a provider which provide this feature by a web service. You will do a request to its server (you need to learn about using external service by android, right way by asynchronous task. Retrofit is a good choice for doing it), and the provider will proccess your request and it will send the SMS by the parameters sending into the request. Beside, the provider depends of your country as well.

Comment: @zeeshansarfraz You mind to accept my answer and raise some flags if they helped you. That will reward my efford... Thanks... :)